Cannot access Google Cloud Storage bucket from GitHub Actions Workflow
I have the Django test case test_retrieve_bucket to test access to a GCP storage bucket.
from django.test import SimpleTestCase, TestCase
from google.cloud import storage

class DemoTest(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.expense = Expense.objects.create(
        invoice_number = "ABC",
        account_number = "123",
        customer_name = "XYZ",
        invoice_amount = 12.50,
        invoice_date = datetime.now()
    )
def test1(self):
    return self.expense.invoice_number == "ABC"
def test2(self):
    return self.expense.account_number == "123"
def test3(self):
    return self.expense.customer_name == "XYZ"

def test_retrieve_bucket(self):
    bucket = "test_bucket_8866"
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket)
    return self.assertTrue(bucket.exists())

However, the test fails, and this is the error I am receiving:

google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/test_bucket_8866?fields=name&prettyPrint=false: test-service-account@tbi-finance.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

I successful authenticated the service account with Workload Identity Federation in the previous step:

The service account I used also has Storage Object Admin permission, which should give me access to the bucket:

Here is my workflow file:
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.12.4]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: auth
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2.0.0
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/334572487877/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/learn-github-actions-pool/providers/github-cdci'
        service_account: 'test-service-account@tbi-finance.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py test
permissions:
  contents: 'read'
  id-token: 'write'


When I ran the Django tests locally with the service account above, all of the tests passed. Is there anything else I'm missing?
Edit:
This was the command I used to add the role WorkloadIdentityUser  to Workload Identity Pool:
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "test-service-account@tbi-finance.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
        --project="tbi-finance" \
        --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \
        --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/334572487877/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/learn-github-actions-pool/attribute.repository/duybtr/django_cdci"


Your configuration looks good and your question is comprehensive (thank you). I'm not super familiar with WIF with GitHub but there's a caveat in the docs: "Workload Identity Pool must have roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser permissions on the target Google Cloud Service Account". Did you complete this step? It could explain why the Service Account works standalone but not under WIF

Yes it does. Thank you for checking. I just added a clearer screenshot of the service account's permissions.

The screenshot shows that the Service Account (test-service-account) as a principal (--member) has the roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser but the Service Account should be used as a resource (!) in which the --member is the Workload Identity pool

This was the command I used to add the policy binding:
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "test-service-account@tbi-finance.iam.gserviceaccount.com" 
--project="tbi-finance" 
--role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" 
--member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/334572487877/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/learn-github-actions-pool/attribute.repository/duybtr/django_cdci"

Ah, Ok. My apologies. That's correct ;-)

No worries! Thanks again.

I was able to get a repro of your solution working but....Oh boy!
In the interests of simplicity, I'm going to enumerate the various resources that I created and I hope that you're able to infer the difference that get you working.
Per this comment I encourage you to add:

the GitHub OIDC Debugger after checkout and before auth
token_format: access_token (if not already)

steps:
- name: checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
- name: oidc-debugger
  uses: github/actions-oidc-debugger@main
  with:
    audience: https://iam.googleapis.com/{PROVIDER}
- name: auth
  uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
  with:
    workload_identity_provider: {PROVIDER}
    service_account: {EMAIL}
    create_credentials_file: true
    token_format: access_token

Be wary of red-herrings. I received a different error than you but this is the result of misconfiguration and not because the Google Project's IAM was incorrect:

Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: failed to generate Google Cloud OAuth 2.0 Access Token for ${EMAIL}:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Pool
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools describe ${POOL} \
  --project="${PROJECT}" \
  --location="global"

displayName: GitHub Actions Pool
name: projects/{NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/{POOL}
state: ACTIVE

Provider
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers describe ${PROVIDER} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--location="global" \
--workload-identity-pool=${POOL}

attributeCondition: assertion.repository_owner=="{OWNER}" && assertion.repository=="{OWNER}/{REPO}"
attributeMapping:
  attribute.actor: assertion.actor
  attribute.repository: assertion.repository
  attribute.repository_owner: assertion.repository_owner
  google.subject: assertion.sub
displayName: {PROVIDER}
name: projects/{NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/{POOL}/providers/{PROVIDER}
oidc:
  issuerUri: https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
state: ACTIVE

Project IAM
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT}

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:{EMAIL}
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
- members:
  - user:{ME}
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:{EMAIL}
  role: roles/storage.admin
etag: [REDACTED]
version: 1


NOTE Per my comment, there's no roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser on the Project's policy; this role is present on the Service Account's policy

Service Account IAM
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ${EMAIL}

bindings:
- members:
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/{NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/{POOL}/attribute.repository/{OWNER}/{REPO}
  role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
etag: [REDACTED]
version: 1

Variables



Name
Value




ACCOUNT
Service Account


EMAIL
Service Account email address: ${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com


ME
My Google account


NUMBER
Google Cloud Project number


OWNER
GitHub User Account or ${ORG}


POOL
Workload Identity Pool


PROJECT
Google Cloud Project ID


PROVIDER
Workload Identity Provider


REPO
GitHub  repo name




Did you add a 'permissions' section at the end of your workflow file?

Yes (to the GitHub Actions workflow YAML)

I added another test case to access Google Cloud Secret Manager, and the workflow runs fine.  So, I think the service account can access resources, but it cannot access Cloud Storage for some reason.
